# What's the fastest query to get limited (but different) number of articles from multiple categories?

Tags: mysql, performance

For the homepage of a news portal (powered by PHP and MySQL), I need to get 9 articles from one category, 9 articles from  another category and 28 latest articles from any categories. Which is the fastest way to do it?

I found some solutions that deal with getting a specified number of articles from multiple categories in a single query, but they all return the same number of articles for every category, which doesn't fit my problem. And also they use an IF statement, which i have a feeling wouldn't be best speed-wise(?)

Should i just do 3 queries? Or use UNION ALL to put it all in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve what you're trying to do in a (non `UNION` or subselect) query.

In terms of multiple queries vs a UNION or sub-select it depends on how fast the query is. Multiple small queries might incur repeated overhead in querying/fetching responses. In terms of concurrency and playing nicely with other queries more smaller queries generally tends to be nicer to a database in terms of contending against other queries.

Answer (score 0):

When you do one query with `union` or `union all`, it will be faster than three separate queries, because you save the communication overhead.

Also consider `union` instead of `union all`, because `union all` retains duplicate rows.